# Using sed to replace part of a text based on a regular expression result

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to read a log file and look for the text `<KEY>any_number_here</KEY>` and `<KEYVAL>any_number_hereDany_number_here</KEYVAL>` and replace those numbers so it looks like this:

`<KEY>*************5683</KEY>` and `<KEYVAL>*************5683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>`

This is an example of the log line:

```
2016/02/01 04:20:21 [18f][00000000000001526][0][00000000000000] Some text here: [size: 000 communication_format: ISO0000 data: "<Document xmlns='bla'><KEY>44444444444445683</KEY><DATE>2017-05</DATE><DATA>2</DATA><KEYVAL>44444444444445683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>"]
```

Notice the **D** separating values on `<KEYVAL>`.

This is my first time trying `sed` and I could get the value inside the `<KEY>` tag but I don't know how to work on that value and replace part of it  with `*`

I have only the expression to get what's inside the `<KEY>` tag:

```
sed -e 's/<KEY>\([[:digit:]]*\)<\/KEY>/ANOTHER SUBSTITUTION HERE?/' test.log
```

**UPDATE**
Now I have this solution, which is the closest I got to what I need:

```
sed -e 's/<KEY>[[:digit:]]\{13\}/(&)/g' -e 's/(.*)/<KEY>*************/g' pan.txt
```

The problem with that is that it is replacing any `()` it finds with `<KEY>*************` and there are several `()` in the log file.

**UPDATE 2**

I think I found the solution:

```
sed -e 's/<KEY>[[:digit:]]\{13\}/(&)/g' -e 's/(.*)/<KEY>*************/g' pan.txt
```

This is working only for the `KEY` tag.

Comment: @anubhava not, it can be any number, that's just an example. The only guarantee is that it will be a number under `<KEY>`. I need to show only the last 4 digits

Comment: Or they keys always the same length, or does the length vary?

Comment: @BenjaminW. 13 with * and the remaining 4. But there is also the `KEYVAL` to consider but it could be executed on another `sed` command, doesn't need to be one command

Comment: And within KEYVAL, the length is also constant?

Comment: @BenjaminW. until the separator `D` it is constant, the same number in `KEY`

Comment: But the number of digits doesn't change?

Comment: After `D` it can change, before `D` it doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
$ sed -r ':a;s|(<KEY>\**)[0-9]([0-9]*[0-9]{4}</KEY>)|\1*\2|;s|(<KEYVAL>\**)[0-9]([0-9]*[0-9]{4}D[^<]*</KEYVAL>)|\1*\2|;ta' <<< "$var"
2016/02/01 04:20:21 [18f][00000000000001526][0][00000000000000] Some text here: [size: 000 communication_format: ISO0000 data: "<Document xmlns=bla><KEY>*************5683</KEY><DATE>2017-05</DATE><DATA>2</DATA><KEYVAL>*************5683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>"]
```

This handles any number of digits and always just leaves the last four. To allow for this flexibility, the overall structure of the command is as follows:

```
:label   # Label to branch to
s///     # Substitute one digit for <KEY>
s///     # Substitute one digit for <KEYVAL>
t label  # If a substitution took place, branch back to 'label'
```

So as long any of the substitutions did something, we loop back and try to replace another digit using the `t` command (conditional branching).

Now, for the substitutions, they look as follows:

```
s|(<KEY>\**)[0-9]([0-9]*[0-9]{4}</KEY>)|\1*\2|
```

This uses two capture groups: one that contains `<KEY>` and however many `*` are after it. Then comes a single, uncaptured digit (which we'll replace in this loop), and then the second capture group consisting of `[0-9]*[0-9]{4}</KEY>`, i.e., any number of digits ending in four digits and `</KEY>`. The substitution simply replaces the uncaptured digit with an asterisk.

Notice that I use extended regular expressions (`-r` option) so I don't have to escape `()`, and the pipe `|` as delimiter so I don't have to escape `/`.

The second substitution is almost the same:

```
s|(<KEYVAL>\**)[0-9]([0-9]*[0-9]{4}D[^<]*</KEYVAL>)|\1*\2|
```

The only difference is that it looks for `KEYVAL` instead of `KEY`, and between the closing tag and the four digits to be kept there is `D[^<]*`, i.e., a `D` followed by any number of characters other than the opening angle bracket.

#### Alternative solution without looping

Definitely no one-liner material, but potentially faster for huge log files:

```
h        # Copy pattern space to hold space

# Remove everything except digits we want to replace from pattern space
s|.*<KEY>(.*)[0-9]{4}</KEY>.*|\1|

s/./*/g  # Replace digits with '*'
G        # Append hold space to pattern space

# Rearrange pattern space
s|(.*)\n(.*<KEY>).*([0-9]{4}</KEY>.*)$|\2\1\3|

# And the the same for the KEYVAL part
h
s|.*<KEYVAL>(.*)[0-9]{4}D.*</KEYVAL>.*|\1|
s/./*/g
G
s|(.*)\n(.*<KEYVAL>).*([0-9]{4}D.*</KEYVAL>.*)$|\2\1\3|
```

This has to be stored in a separate file (some seds don't like the comments, so they can be removed) and then called like this:

```
$ sed -rf sedscr.sed <<< "$var"
2016/02/01 04:20:21 [18f][00000000000001526][0][00000000000000] Some text here: [size: 000 communication_format: ISO0000 data: "<Document xmlns=bla><KEY>*************5683</KEY><DATE>2017-05</DATE><DATA>2</DATA><KEYVAL>*************5683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat inputfile 
2016/02/01 04:20:21 [18f][00000000000001526][0][00000000000000] Some text here: [size: 000 communication_format: ISO0000 data: "<Document xmlns='bla'><KEY>44444444444445683</KEY><DATE>2017-05</DATE><DATA>2</DATA><KEYVAL>44444444444445683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>"]

$ egrep -o -e '<KEY>[0-9]+</KEY>' -e '<KEYVAL>[0-9]+D[0-9]+</KEYVAL>' inputfile | sed -r -e 's/^(<KEY>.*)([0-9]{4})(<\/KEY>)$/\1\n\2\3/g;' -e 's/^(<KEYVAL>.*)([0-9]{4}D[0-9]+)(<\/KEYVAL>)$/\1\n\2\3/g' | sed -e '1~2 s/[0-9]/*/g' | sed -n 'N;s/\n//g;p'
<KEY>*************5683</KEY>
<KEYVAL>*************5683D00000000000000000000</KEYVAL>
```

This handles any number of digits before 5683 in KEY, also it handles any number of digits before and after `5683D` in KEYVAL. Also 5683 can be can be any 4 digits.